# Cannot install Oracle Application server

Tags: windows-server-2003, oracle10g, application-server

After succesfull installation of database 10g server, I cannot run install file for application server - it closed unexpectly.

How can be problem investigated?

Log file contains:

```
Checking installer requirements...

Checking operating system version: must be 5.0, 5.1 or 5.2.    Actual 5.2
                                      Passed

Checking monitor: must be configured to display at least 256 colors.    Actual 4294967296    Passed
Checking swap space: must be greater than 1535 MB.   Actual 4092MB    Passed
Checking Temp space: must be greater than 150 MB.   Actual 5083 MB    Passed

All installer requirements met.
```

Answer (score 0):

Try searching under $Oracle_home/oraInventory\Logs  . The name of the log will be installactions*.log